# Angularjs login page error.

Tags: angularjs

I have been getting this error and I couldn't find a solution yet. This is my console error. I tried googling for solutions but it shows the Object.parse error. I have not used any json.parse() function too.

```
angular.js:11500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
at Object.parse (native)
at oc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:14:136)
at Yb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:76:271)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:77:117
at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:7:302)
at Vc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:77:99)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:78:205)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:111:252
at k.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:125:120)
at k.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:122:218)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11500(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8479(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13083k.$eval @ angular.js:14291k.$digest @ angular.js:14107k.$apply @ angular.js:14395m @ angular.js:9569N @ angular.js:9756w.onload @ angular.js:9697
```

This is my controller.js file

```
app.controller('logincontrol', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.loginData = null;
$http.get('/newshop/JSON/login.json')
  .success( function (data) {
    $scope.loginData = data;
  })

$scope.login = function( user ) {
for( var i = 0; i < $scope.loginData.length; i++) {
    var temp = $scope.loginData[i];
    if(user.name === temp.username && user.password === temp.password ){
        alert("Hurray!");
        break;
    } else {
      alert("Fails!");
    }
}
}});
```

This is my login.json file

```
[
  {
"username ": "admin",
"password": "admin",
  },
  {
"username" : "haritha",
"password" : "haritha123",
  },
  {
"username" : "harry",
"password" : "harrypotter"
   }
]
```

This is my login.html file.

```
  <body ng-app= "loginapp">
  <div class= "container" ng-controller="logincontrol">
    <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x custom-icon"></i></div>
    <form action="" id="login">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Username" ng-model= "user.name" ><br>
          <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" ng-model= "user.password" ><br>
          <button  class="btn-login" type="button" ng-click= "submit(user)"> Login </button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Please check working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z9qrvB?p=preview)

Following mistakes are there in your code,

1. In login.json

   ```
   [{
       "username ": "admin",
       "password": "admin" , <-- Comma, because of this you get that above error please remove it 
   }, {
       "username": "haritha",
       "password": "haritha123", <-- Comma, because of this you get that above error please remove it   
   }, {
       "username": "harry",
       "password": "harrypotter"
   }]
   ```
2. Name of function you are calling is different that you defined it in controller.
   In HTML

   ng-click="submit(user)"

   In controller.js
   you are calling **$scope.login**
3. You don't required to pass "user" to that function, you are not using angularjs Two-way data binding feature. You can access that value directly in function using **$scope**

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  {
"username ": "admin",
"password": "admin",
  },
  {
"username" : "haritha",
"password" : "haritha123",
  },
  {
"username" : "harry",
"password" : "harrypotter"
   }
]
```

This is not a valid json. Below is the valid one:

```
[
  {
    "username ": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  },
  {
    "username" : "haritha",
    "password" : "haritha123"
  },
  {
    "username" : "harry",
    "password" : "harrypotter"
  }
]
```

You can validate your `json` files through online `json` `lint`ers like http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The only 'bad' thing I can see in this code is that you forgot a `;`

```
app.controller('logincontrol', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.loginData = null;
    $http.get('/newshop/JSON/login.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.loginData = data;
        }); //  <--------

    $scope.login = function (user) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.loginData.length; i++) {
            var temp = $scope.loginData[i];
            if (user.name === temp.username && user.password === temp.password) {
                alert("Hurray!");
                break;
            } else {
                alert("Fails!");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Everything else here seems ok, so if this does not fix your issues, then it must be another piece of code causing the error.

**EDIT:**

Probably your JSON packet was not properly arranged.
I can see some unnessecary comma's in it too.

More info is found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11513)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change you login.json to

```
[
 {
  "username ": "admin",
  "password": "admin" // Remove this comma
 },
{
 "username" : "haritha",
 "password" : "haritha123" // Remove this comma
 },
 {
  "username" : "harry",
  "password" : "harrypotter"
 }
]
```

and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to JSON. By default Angular expects the response to be JSON, no need of using JSON.parse() so no cause of error.

But here you are getting the data from JSON, where in your case the structure is not correct so you got this error (due to extra coma you used in your JSON file).

Better try [JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) for structuring your JSON.

And also better to avoid using of alerts.
Alert is a terrible debugging tool